# Скачать файл с sftp с помощью paramiko

Tags: python, python-3.x, sftp, paramiko

Есть sftp сервер, на который раз в день загружается 1 файл. К примеру, сегодня там файл `primer1.txt`, а завтра к нему прибавится `primer2.txt`, и на сервере будут храниться уже два файла. Можно ли скачать последний загруженный файл, не зная его имени?

Comment: А обязательно paramiko? Просто это bash скриптом на раз делается

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я делаю для своей задачи примерно так:

```
directory_name = 'some_directory/'

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(
    host,
    username=my_username,
    password=my_password,
    key_filename=my_key_file
)

commands = ['cd {0}'.format(directory_name), 'ls -1t | tail -1']
commands_str = '; '.join(commands)

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(commands_str)

last_modified_fname = stdout.readlines()[-1][:-1] # получено нужное имя

sftp = ssh.open_sftp()    
sftp.get(directory_name + last_modified_fname, 'any_file_name_i_want')
```

Здесь `ls -1t | tail -1` выводит имя последнего изменённого файла, но в виде списка из одного элемента и с добавленным `\n` на конце, поэтому собственно имя файла получается как `stdout.readlines()[-1][:-1]`

Answer (score 0):

Окей, я решил. В моем случае файлы названы так, что их можно отсортировать. **Решение частное, для моего случая.**

```
# Стандартные строчки
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(host, port, username, password)
sftp = ssh_zniis.open_sftp()

ls_sftp = sftp_zniis.listdir(remote_path) # Получаем список файлов на sftp
ls_sftp.sort() # сортируем полученный список

# Качаем файл по пути, полученному с помощью конкатенации строк remote_path и последней строки полученного списка
sftp_zniis.get(remote_path+ls_sftp[-1], local_path)
```